# SpriteBatch Draw

Tags: java, libgdx

Ok so i have 3 sprite textures and while i have a stage being drawn with Stage.draw(); only the first two will draw. but if i add a 4th then 3 will draw. However if i remove Stage.draw then everything works as normal (except my labels)

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.3f, .3f, .35f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    game.batch.begin();

    game.batch.draw(headbox, HEADBOX_X, HEADBOX_Y, HEADBOX_W,HEADBOX_H);

    game.batch.draw(textbox, TEXTBOX_X, TEXTBOX_Y, TEXTBOX_W,TEXTBOX_H);




    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.ESCAPE)){
        //TODO: Pause menu
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.ENTER) && labelCount < Labels.size() - 1){
        Labels.get(labelCount).remove();
        labelCount++;
        stage.addActor(Labels.get(labelCount));
    }
    if(labelCount == 5){
        game.batch.draw(jame, HEADA_X, HEADA_Y, HEADA_W, HEADA_H);
        System.out.println("drawing");


    }

    stage.draw();
    stage.act();


    game.batch.end();
}
```

In ther code here only the headbox texture will draw until Label count gets to 5 then textbox will draw

Answer (score -1):

I had to put stage.act before batch.begin and stage.draw after batch.end